# Check if insert is successful in ASP.NET with stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, insert

I know it may be an old question but I'm confused about getting "affected row count" using a stored procedure.

Here is my code:

```
public DataSet saveuser(string procedure, string username, string password)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(procedure, connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);

    SqlAdapter adapter = new SqlAdapter(command);
    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(dataset);

    connection.Close();
    return dataset,
}
```

I have tried this code:

```
int rowschanged = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This seemed to help me but when I'm checking database insert was twice.

Do you have any idea? Can I get rows affected count with `SqlDataAdapter`?

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Affected row count" is the return of the query itself, what you can do is change your SP in a way it returns 0 if succeeded or -1 if didn't (can be any other values of course and you will need to perform some sort of error validation in the SP code)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why are you returning DataSet
any way here is the solution if you using DataSet

```
public DataSet saveuser(string procedure, string username, string password)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(procedure, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
            connection.Open();
            adapter.Fill(dataset);
            var count = dataset.Tables?[0].Rows.Count;
            connection.Close();
            return dataset;
        }
```

and if you want to use DataTable

```
public DataTable SaveuserwithDataTable(string procedure, string username, string password)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(procedure, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            connection.Open();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            var count = dt.Rows.Count;
            connection.Close();
            return dt;
        }
```

Wish this help !!